# How can I coarsen an overly fine mesh in Python without losing geometric details?

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh, geometry-surface

I have a following fine mesh as a trimesh.base.Trimesh mesh for a quarter box geometry. This mesh is good at capturing geometric details such as the tight fillet radii, but it is unnecessary fine all over, which makes it computationally expensive. For example, the flat planar regions do not need to be so fine.
[image: Fine mesh]

I want to coarsen this mesh to remove the computational burden, but I want to keep fine details, such as tight radii. So far, I have tried the following:

```
myMesh = myMesh.simplify_quadratic_decimation(2000)
```

Which uses a quadratic decimation algorithm to simplify the mesh to only have 2000 faces, as opposed to 50,000+ before (https://trimsh.org/trimesh.base.html). Here is the mesh it produces:

[image: Coarsened using quadratic decimation]

It works, and radii regions still have locally finer mesh, but the mesh becomes messy. What I would like is a mesh which looks like the following, where the mesh is neat, not too many elements, and accurately captures geometric details:

[image: Desired mesh]

I've not been able to find any resources online and this is not my field of expertise. Does anyone know how I can achieve the above neat mesh?

Best regards

Comment: Nice pictures!!!  You could just run it longer?   there is another package `pyfqmr` that does mesh reduction and allows you to set error tolerance, and also "lossless" mode.  Maybe that will be helpful.